# C# windows service profiling using Glimpse

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-management, windows-services, profiler, glimpse

We have windows service written in C# and wanted to monitor which method taking more time, memory leaks/allocation etc.

Is it possible to profile windows service using glimpse profiler?
Or any other best profiler to monitor windows service?

(We have tried PerfView and DebugDiag but wanted to look in some other way too.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Glimpse works based on primitives in ASP.NET (HttpModule, HttpHandler), so it wouldn't be compatible with a standard Windows service.

I'd recommend trying a CPU Profiler like the ones that Red Gate and JetBrains sell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nik. Unfortunately Red Gate and JetBrains both are paid versions and we are looking for free ware.